# how to use webservice using nusoap library php

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

i have try to use the webservice from some site, 
i use nusoap library and my php code like this

```
  <?php
   require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

   $client = new SoapClient("http://simlitabmas.dikti.go.id/ws_pimnas/ws.svc?wsdl");

  $err = $client->getError();
  if ($err) {
      echo '<h2>errorr BOSSSS </h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
  }

  $param = "examplekeyword";
  $param2 = "001029";
  $result = $client->call('get_peserta',array("keyword"=>"$param","kode_perguruan_tinggi"=>"$param2"));


if (!empty($result)) {

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#cccccc'>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Nomor Mahasiswa</th>";

echo "</tr>";
foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$item['nama']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$item['nomor_mahasiswa']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

}
 ?>
```

The function get_peserta has two parameter to input.
when i test my php code i got blank page. Any help?

Comment: I think you should store all needed data into array and pass the array in `echo json_encode($array);`  it is convert in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the WSDL from http://simlitabmas.dikti.go.id/ws_pimnas/ws.svc?wsdl, you could generate the corresponding package from [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com) in order to be sure on how to structure your request in PHP as every element will be a PHP object with setters/getters. Let me know if you need any additional help,

Comment: thanks you very much, when i execute that webservice in  wsdltophp.com, i get response like this `PHP response  
 
Pimnas28StructGet_dosenPendampingResponse Object
(
    [get_dosenPendampingResult] => eyJyZXN1bHQiOiJcIkZhbHNlXCIiLCJkYXRhIjoiXCJLZXl3b3JkIGFuZGEgc2FsYWguLi5cIiJ9
)` how i use that response to see the data i want.

Comment: How i update the parameter in this  code bellow `$pimnas28ServiceGet_jml_record_dosen = new Pimnas28ServiceGet_jml_record_dosen();
// sample call for Pimnas28ServiceGet_jml_record_dosen::get_jml_record_dosenPendamping()

if($pimnas28ServiceGet_jml_record_dosen->get_jml_record_dosenPendamping(new Pimnas28StructGet_jml_record_dosenPendamping(/*** update parameters list ***/)))
    print_r($pimnas28ServiceGet_jml_record_dosen->getResult());
else
    print_r($pimnas28ServiceGet_jml_record_dosen->getLastError());` I get this code from  wsdltophp.com. I have two parameter to pass.

Comment: each class contains setters and getters that allows you to set or get the data from the object so get_dosenPendampingResult should be accessible using the getGet_dosenPendampingResult method I guess. Concerning the call to get_jml_record_dosenPendamping, you must look to the Pimnas28StructGet_jml_record_dosenPendamping class in order to know what has to be modified in the place of /*** update parameters list ***/

Comment: or you can simply try the online interface using Execute tab that allows you to send request from the online web form interface

Comment: thanks you for your reply, by the way  wsdltophp.com  is awesome , i have try the online interface  using Execute, i input  my two parameter in the execute page, but i don't understand with the result, i mean, why the result like this `PHP response Pimnas28StructGet_dosenPendampingResponse Object ( [get_dosenPendampingResult] => eyJyZXN1bHQiOiJcIkZhbHNlXCIiLCJkYXRhIjoiXCJLZXl3b3JkIGFuZGEgc2FsYWguLi5cIiJ9 )` what type of data is this?, do i need some conversion to convers this data?

Comment: At this step, I think you should ask to the Web Service provider as the platform does not alter in any way the request nor the response data. The data is encoded in base64 apparently, try your response at https://www.base64decode.org/. This part is on you then.